# Add library/module to server

Tags: python, server, module, pip, pymupdf

I am pretty new to python and would like to use the PyMuPDF library on a web server in order to modify PDFs. The problem is, I am unable to add/install any modules or libraries to/on the server.

Is there a way to install all libraries and modules in a directory, then upload this directory to the server and link the python file (also on server) to these uploaded folders?

Comment: How is the web server hosted? How do you normally deploy code to it?

Comment: The server is hosted by manitu (german webhosting company). I usally use a FTP client (FileZilla) to upload files.